# Prevent masterpage from adding formatting to html

Tags: 2013, master-page

I have a `CustomMasterPage.html` that I've put a `<textarea></textarea>` on the page.

Every time I upload the html page, SharePoint formats the textarea tag by indenting it and the breaking the closing tag to the next line. It does this for all the html tags on my page, but normally the page render skips all that white space.

With the textarea however it takes that as the default value for the text area and when the user clicks into the text area it is already full of spaces.

I've tried to google, but all the results come back about removing all the various giant padding/margins that SP adds and I can't find anything about stopping the masterpage from reworking my html.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are out of luck.

There is no Server Side setting, its just how SharePoint (mis)behaves on the HTML it creates (Server Side) or manages (Client Side) or rewrites (Server Side again)

When you add WebParts to zones, SharePoint also rewrites the HTML and adds (less harmful) P and BR tags.

You could ductape JavaScript code into `onload` and `onunload` events and delete the rework SP did, but you have to ask if the investment is worth it